# How to connect 2 laptops to separate monitor and work simultaneously?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

There are two of us with Mac book pros working on the same project and we'd like to connect our work to one one single monitor as we work to be able to share ideas and build the presentation we are working on together... how can we do this?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You can only choose one input for the monitor. You could use Google Docs, which allows multiple people to edit the same document.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible.  You cannot have two inputs on a monitor simultaneously display.

What you need is to do is have one of the laptops hooked up to the monitor and *share* that desktop to other users.  Skype, Go2Meeting, TeamViewer and other screen sharing and collaboration software have this capability.

Comment: Thank you all for your insight and advice - really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't possible, you do have options and avenues for having multiple people edit a single presentation in real-time (it's a lot of fun!)

1. [Real-Time editing a Prezi](https://prezi.com/support/article/creating/co-editing-with-prezi/).
2. [Real-Time editing a Google Presentation](http://google.com/slides).
3. [Real-Time editing a Microsoft Powerpoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-together-on-Office-documents-in-OneDrive-ea3807bc-2b73-406f-a8c9-a493de18258b).

Seriously. Don't have too much fun - it gets out of control with lots of people working on a single project. :)